# Why ubuntu has several desktops?

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, kubuntu, ubuntu-gnome, ubuntu-mate

I'm a new Ubuntu user (unity) v16.04. I loved the interface of unity but at the same time I want to check Ubuntu mate.

Why? because:

- it allows me to view 4 windows (in the 4 quarters).
- Also I love one of his interfaces that looks like Mac.
- Supportes animations like mac when max/minimizing windows.
- Finally, its repository contains chrome and a lot of apps that are not in Ubuntu Unity's repository.

So, my question is:

- Why are there several Ubuntu desktops? This make the users confused and unable to decide which desktop contains his requirements.
- Are all Ubuntu desktops (Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Mate, Gnome, etc...) supported forever or not?
- (optional question) Which Ubuntu desktop is easiest and contains the most needed requirements for normal users?

Comment: The correct question should be "why not?" This makes *you* confused, perhaps, but others appreciate the freedom of choice. And you're asking for opinions and that is off topic.

Comment: Some simple answers:
Why so many desktops: choice. Ubuntu is derived from Debian. Mate is derived from Ubuntu, for example, and was created because the original developer wanted something "different".
Chromium [not Chrome] IS available for Ubuntu.
Which is easiest : that is a simple question with 1000 different answers. It is a point of view, but I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity.
Ubuntu does the 4 windows thing.
Support for ever ? No, nothing is forever. However LTS [Long Term Support] is the most stable and gets the longest period of support.
Mac: Look at Budgie.

Comment: MATE : Right click on the "Workspace Switcher", select 'Preferences', and you can select the number of Desktops from **one** to "many". ( I prefer MATE, and I usually have 13 Desktops ! )

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, welcome to Ubuntu. In my mind, the simple answer as to why there are so many desktops is because Linux (and the vast majority of Ubuntu code) is free and open source. Xfce, Unity and Mate etc are independant projects and people are free to do what they please with the code (within the license of course). Users have choice.

To me, it is like asking "why do we have Ford Fiestas, Maxda MX-5s and Landrover Discoveries"; they all get you from A to B yet they are all independant products.

My advice is not to worry about what desktop environment you choose, they all run on top of the Ubuntu OS and, within reason, all receive the same amount of support. Pick a desktop that works best for you and, well, use it.

Which users do you think are confused, do you mean yourself ?

Nothing is supported for ever. The Ubuntu LTS releases are supported for 5 years and the non LTS releases are supported for 9 months. Nothing is supported for ever.

Most needed requirements for a normal user is a difficult question. Define normal ! That said, I always steer new users to either Ubuntu Mate or Xubuntu, as they offer (in my opinion) a more traditional desktop experience.

Answer (score 2):

The different desktops are from the broader Linux community, and they exist because some people like one more than others... that's about it, personal taste.

Linux being open-source and largely community maintained, anyone can write their own projects/programs, and if you really want to change a few things about an existing program (ex. window manager, desktop) you can "fork" it, creating a "similar yet different" version. I think that's happened several times, MATE is one that comes to mind.

If you think there's lots of Ubuntu "flavours", you should do some web/Wikipedia browsing, there's [15 different "X Window System desktop environments"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_Window_System_desktop_environments), and [at least 38 "X window managers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_window_managers), nearly any of which can be installed on any Ubuntu.

I believe the different Ubuntu "flavours" (Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, etc) are basically variations on the main "Ubuntu Desktop Edition, simply called Ubuntu" (as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)) puts it). They take the main edition and add & remove packages, change the desktop & some settings & artwork... In theory you could take any Ubuntu flavour and turn it back into a default Ubuntu if you wanted, or vice versa.

You should be able to install any program in the Ubuntu repositories onto any Ubuntu "flavour," some might just have large dependencies (ex. K desktop programs). Or install a few different desktop environments & window managers at the same time, to choose between them as you wish.

---

*"Are all ubuntu desktop... supported for ever"* - No Ubuntu is supported forever, the releases get 9 months to 5 years of support (for an LTS) at the most.

---

Might want to browse [Wikipedia's Ubuntu page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)) for some general info, and if you like animations see [compiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz) (it's still being maintained, as compiz-reloaded?) for some nice ones (desktop cube, "burn," etc). Here's some still images below, or just search the web for videos [like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QokOwvPxrE), or this [longer review about compiz-reloaded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_OTHYCenHk):

[image: compiz cube] [image: burn] [image: dream]